# Linux file permission for a folder

Tags: linux

I'm checking for the folder permission and when I do "ls -al", I get the following...

```
drwxr-xr-x 18 t3dev  root 4096 May 12 10:16 docs
```

Im trying to understand what is the difference between "t3dev" vs "root"...t3dev is the

Answer (score 1):

t3dev is the user the directory belongs to; root is the group that it belongs to. This link gives a pretty thorough rundown of permissions: http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/19060-unix-file-permissions.html